# MVC Redirect after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AccountController where users can login, and an area named Admin where users have to been autorized to see. When users log in with correct username and pw, it redirects to the same page again (`../Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin`)

AccountController

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.Username == "User" && model.Password == "Pa$$W0rd")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin"});
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Brukernavn og/eller passord er feil");
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

AdminController in area Admin

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : HimmelhoytControllerBase
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

View Login

```
@model Himmelhoyt.Models.AccountModels.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Logg inn";
}
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
    {
        < text>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "sr-only" }) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Brukernavn", autofocus = "autofocus" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "bg-danger validationMessage" })

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "sr-only" }) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Passord", type = "password" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "bg-danger validationMessage" })
            <br/>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RememberMe@*, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "checkbox" } }*@) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            <br />
            @Html.Submit("Logg på", new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" })

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        </text>
    }
```

In the Account-controller, `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin" });` is executed, but as I said, it only redirects to the same page.

**EDITED**
Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Himmelhoyt-20140831071527.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Himmelhoyt-20140831071527;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HimmelhoytDb" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=Himmelhoyt;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Change your 'RedirectToAction' to what page you are going to be redirected after you log.in.. You put there 'Index','Admin' so you are returning to the index of Admin. :3

Comment: Check in the debugger what value the `returnUrl` variable has.
if `return Redirect(returnUrl);` is executed, and returnUrl is correct(I mean url is not equal to "/Account/Login"), check if the cookies are correctly set.

Comment: @ViktorArsanov returnUrl is NULL (that is also a problem a problem, but deal woth that later), so it will execute return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin"}); I'm new in C#, how to check if the cookies are correctly set?

Comment: @user4034034 First, check your browsers settings
Such situation looks like cookies are not set.
Then, I would set a breakpoint on the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` in the `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)` method and in the Watch debugger window would check the controller User property.
Check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property - it should be equal to true.

Comment: check if cookie has been created successfully and did you checked through fiddler ?

Comment: Also check your web.config file. There may be some settings that forbid any user to log in.(<authorization> element with wrong settings)

Comment: Please share your config

Comment: user4034034, have you tried my answer?

Comment: @ViktorArsanov Cookies is enabled, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false. Shuold I set this to true, or should it be done automaticly (and something else is wrong)? I pasted web.config in my question, I think everything there is ok.

Comment: @user4034034 I've answered, it is the only thing I can imagine, if you can reproduce the problem in different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the following lines from your Web.config

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Comment: When I removed that, it wasn't authorizing at all. However, the redirect was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

move this method from the `Account` controller to the `Admin` controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.Username == "User" && model.Password == "Pa$$W0rd")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin"});
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Brukernavn og/eller passord er feil");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And change the controller call in your View from:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
```

to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
```

Then change a line in the method you moved to the Admin Controller, from:

```
return View();
```

to:

```
return Redirect("Index");
```

See if it works and suits your needs

Comment: I think the problem is that auth cookies isn't set.The method should work at the place I have it, because I follow an example where it's done and work.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, I can see that you set SetAuthCookie if the user provide correct credentials but you haven't sign in yet. because of that you always redirected to the login page.

I think you have to sign in in order to see the admin section. Use your sing in methods to sign in.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.Username == "User" && model.Password == "Pa$$W0rd")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);

                //Sign in code should go here.

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin"});
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Brukernavn og/eller passord er feil");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

What is the authentication method you used in your application? Is it Asp.net Identity framework?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I'm feeling so stupid. I trying to do something I learned on a course a few weeks ago, and in his program he havn't any code between FormAut.. and if-statement, that works. Is the Asp.net Identity framework something you recomend for beginners? Then I should look at that.

Comment: Yes, if you are using latest technologies I mean above .net framework 4.5 and Visual studio 2012, 2013, I strongly recommend to use identity framework. You can find all the required examples here  http://www.asp.net/identity. If you think, is that you looking for, mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is okay but for your problem I did as follows:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
return RedirectToAction("RedirectLogin", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl});

public ActionResult RedirectLogin(string returnUrl)
{
   return User.IsInRole("Reader") ? RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees") : RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

And if you do not want it to be "Home" or "Index" as default, change this:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
  if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
  {
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
 }
```

Everything in your AccountController, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string securityIsnuul(string id)
{
    agancyEntities db = new agancyEntities();

    if (id == null)
    {
      //// redirect to url??????
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand this answer to include an explanation of why you think this will resolve the problem?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Your this line of code
    `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Admin"});`

might be throwing exception. Try

1. putting a try catch and see what is the exception.
2. You are passing value , but your index method in Admin does not take any param. Check this.

Comment: No exception is thrown. The param says it should go to the area named Admin, I think. I also tried return Redirect("~/Admin"), because thats the route for my Admin-index.