# How To redirect to same area where login happen after successfully login

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller, razor

```
[Hotpots]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel,string area)
   {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
         var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email,loginViewModel.Password,oginViewModel.RememberMe, false);
                if (result. Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home", new { area=area});
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError(string. Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
            }
            return View(LoginViewModel);
     }
```

```
Now After Successful login I want to redirect to same area how to do that
```

Comment: similar Link---https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804518/mvc-redirect-after-login

Comment: Any update ?If you feel my reply has helped you. Please mark it as answer. So that other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could not directly achieve the redirection simply adding the string parameter 'area' in the 'Login' action.
Instead, you should pass the area value in the 'Login' process

> • The first thing is to pass the area name when an user clicks the
> login button
> •  Then the area name should be passed to the login
> action when the user complete the input of the user credentials.
> • The last step is to use the area value to redirect to the home index
> of the area after the successful login

The key is that you should store the area name before start the login processs.

With the previous codes I provided you, you could check the below codes for more details.

_LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" asp-area="">
            <button type="submit" style="width: auto" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                Logout @User.Identity.Name
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="area" value="@ViewContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["area"]" />
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-area="" asp-route-areaName="@ViewContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["area"]">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Account controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string area) 
        {

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home", new { area = area });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string areaName)
        {
            ViewBag.Area = areaName;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, string areaName)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home",new { area = areaName });
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
            }
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
```

Login.cshtml:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-area="">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-areaName="@ViewBag.Area">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-controller="Account"  asp-area="" asp-action="ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-area="">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Demo:

[image]